# c is it possible to copy a string on initialization of a member in a struct?

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, initialization

What i am trying to do is to copy(not pointing) `stringToCopy` on to the struct member `aString` on it's initialization.

```c
    struct thePrefix {
        unsigned char aString[65];
    };
    
    unsigned char stringToCopy[65]= "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf";
    
    struct thePrefix testing = {
        .aString= stringToCopy //<--- Copying the string(stringToCopy) here
    };
```

is it possible? as you have noticed it i am new to c

Comment: Nope. Welcome to C :(

Comment: Yeah, you basically have to do it manually. It's best to define your own "copy constructor" function, which internally can use this initialization syntax.

Comment: @ Alexander Re:Nope. Welcome to C  okej

Comment: If applicable/appropriate, you can bury your initial content in its own struct, then initialize from that. [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/1WKq5Yf5n).

Comment: @WhozCraig alright thank you, i guess your method is the only option i have

Comment: @WhozCraig is there any reason why you choose to go with a `static struct`?

Comment: Not really. Force of habit more than anything else. It does, however, preserve the ability to put both the struct definition *and* the default in a single header file and use them at-will wherever you include your header (each translation unit gets its own `s_default`, but they're all equivalent in value).

Comment: Did you consider using `strcpy()`?